# unable to form the view using ng-repeat through custom directive template compilation

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-compile, angularjs-templates

I am facing problem in representing ng-repeat in template for custom directive compilation. Please find my plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/5A5oZf5kwBezB4mqZ56C?p=preview. Here even though the question is appearing but the options are not appearing. I am doubting whether my following code in the template formation is correct or not?

```
<div ng-repeat="Option in {{curQuestion.Options}}">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for double curlies inside an ngRepeat expression.

```
<div ng-repeat="option in curQuestion.options">  
    <label for="option.Id" ng-click="onSelect(Option);">   
         <input id="option.Id" type="checkbox" ng-model="option.Selected" />
                 {{option.Name}}  
    </label>   
</div>
```

Double curlies are used for binding the view to the model (telling angular that "option.Name" is not really just plain text but a scope variable).

Inside an "ng-something" attribute - you're basically in the model already, 
that's why

```
{{option.Name}}
```

Is equivalent to

```
<span ng-bind="option.Name"></span>
```

Anyway, here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/iXMYpeus58JeScc122pX?p=preview).